# Resizing uploaded files in django using PIL

Tags: python, django, file-upload, resize, python-imaging-library

I am using PIL to resize an uploaded file using this method:

```
def resize_uploaded_image(buf):
  imagefile = StringIO.StringIO(buf.read())
  imageImage = Image.open(imagefile)

  (width, height) = imageImage.size
  (width, height) = scale_dimensions(width, height, longest_side=240)

  resizedImage = imageImage.resize((width, height))
return resizedImage
```

I then use this method to get the resizedImage in my main view method:

```
image = request.FILES['avatar']
resizedImage = resize_uploaded_image(image)
content = django.core.files.File(resizedImage)
acc = Account.objects.get(account=request.user)
acc.avatar.save(image.name, content)
```

However, this gives me the 'read' error.

Trace:

> Exception Type: AttributeError at /myapp/editAvatar Exception Value:
>   read

Any idea how to fix this? I have been at it for hours!
Thanks!

Nikunj

Comment: a PIL Image object is not a file. You need to `save()` to to a StringIO object first, using some sort of encoding (e.g. PNG). Don't forget to `seek(0)` after writing the file to the StringIO! Side note: Why not just read from `buf` directly and avoid the extra wrapper StringIO?

Comment: Cameron, thanks for your reply. I am really new to this. And I don't really understand whats going on. I was trying to piece together snippets to make it work. How do I save to a StringIO object. Will resizedImage.save().seek(0) in the top most method be good enough? If you can show me a little sample code or a place where this is documented, that would be great :) Thanks.

Comment: As you seem to be concerned with resizing an avatar, which is something pretty common and standard: Instead of resizing the image with PIL directly using an dedicated app like easy_thumbnails (which uses PIL too) might make things easier for you: http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/#python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can take a file-like object, manipulate it as an image in PIL, then turn it back into a file-like object:

```
def resize_uploaded_image(buf):
    image = Image.open(buf)

    (width, height) = image.size
    (width, height) = scale_dimensions(width, height, longest_side=240)

    resizedImage = image.resize((width, height))

    # Turn back into file-like object
    resizedImageFile = StringIO.StringIO()
    resizedImage.save(resizedImageFile , 'PNG', optimize = True)
    resizedImageFile.seek(0)    # So that the next read starts at the beginning

    return resizedImageFile
```

Note that there's already a handy `thumbnail()` method for PIL images. This is a variant of the thumbnail code I use in my own project:

```
def resize_uploaded_image(buf):
    from cStringIO import StringIO
    import Image

    image = Image.open(buf)

    maxSize = (240, 240)
    resizedImage = image.thumbnail(maxSize, Image.ANTIALIAS)

    # Turn back into file-like object
    resizedImageFile = StringIO()
    resizedImage.save(resizedImageFile , 'PNG', optimize = True)
    resizedImageFile.seek(0)    # So that the next read starts at the beginning

    return resizedImageFile
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better for you to save the uploaded image and then display and resize it in template as you wish. This way you will be able to resize images at runtime. [sorl-thumbnail](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail) is djano app which you can use for template image resizing, it is easy to use and you can use it in a view too. Here are [examples](http://thumbnail.sorl.net/examples.html) for this app.